# Python3 - How to replace text in multiple files incrementally with different replacement text for odd and even numbered files

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have a directory of files named p1.html to p20.html. Each file contains the same two lines of text:

```
abc
xyz
```

My goal is to replace the text in the odd numbered files (p1.html, p3.html, ...) to:

```
hello
world
```

and to replace the text in the even numbered files (p2.html, p4.html, ...) to:

```
foo
bar
```

Below is my most recent attempt.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

def pageseq():

count=1
vtxfile="p%d.html" % count

newopname="hello"
newonname="world"
newepname="foo"
newenname="bar"

for i in range(1, 21):
    if i <= 20 and i % 2 == 0:
        with fileinput.FileInput(vtxfile, inplace=True) as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.replace('abc', newopname)
                line = line.replace('xyz', newonname)
                print (line, end='')
        fileinput.close()
        count += 1
        
    elif i <= 20 and i % 2 != 0:
        with fileinput.FileInput(vtxfile, inplace=True) as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.replace('abc', newepname)
                line = line.replace('xyz', newenname)
                print (line, end='')
        fileinput.close()
        count += 1

    else:
        print("Done")

pageseq()
```

For some reason, I can't get the for loop to open each file and make the changes incrementally. Instead, only the first file (p1.html) is modified and the remaining files untouched.

Comment: It's how you define `vtxfile`... `vtxfile="p%d.html" % count` at that moment `count` is `1` and you never change `vtxfile` again after that. If you put that inside of the `for i in range(1, 21):` loop, it *should* work.

Comment: Also note. `count` is essentially irrelevant. You can just use `i` and delete the count variable.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Could you post this as a solution so I can upvote you for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how you define vtxfile... `vtxfile="p%d.html" % count`

The count variable is inserted into the string at the current value and isn't a reference to it.

So each time you update count you need to redefine `vtxfile`.

Putting that variable declaration inside the outer loop will allow it to update each time the loop runs. However, now that it's inside the loop, you can just use the loop counter `i` and get rid of the count variable and all references to it. `vtxfile="p%d.html" % i`

You also don't need to explicitly close the file as it's closed automatically as you leave the `with` statements.

There are a few other optimizations that can be done. The if-elsif-else can be reduced to a single `if` statement.

`if i <= 20 and i % 2 == 0:` So here, you don't need to check below 20 since you limit the range already in the loop declaration you can shorten the `if` to just `if i%2 == 0:`

Since the condition of the loop is full filled for an even number, you can now add a `continue` statement to the if main branch to skip to the next iteration of the loop.

The else can be completely deleted as `i` will never be more than 20.

With the else completely deleted and a `continue` added to the main `if` we can now move the `else if` branch to the out of the `if` logic and make it the default else code.

The full updated code.

```
# Deleted the count and vtxfile lines.

newopname="hello"
newonname="world"
newepname="foo"
newenname="bar"

for i in range(1, 21):
    vtxfile="p%d.html" % i
    if i <= 20 and i % 2 == 0:
        with fileinput.FileInput(vtxfile, inplace=True) as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.replace('abc', newopname)
                line = line.replace('xyz', newonname)
                print (line, end='')
        continue
        
    with fileinput.FileInput(vtxfile, inplace=True) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace('abc', newepname)
            line = line.replace('xyz', newenname)
            print (line, end='')
```

This is just a few of the things I saw immediately. There's a way to merge the two `with` statements as well but I'll leave that up to you to solve. Happy coding!